# iphone textview contents to url?

Tags: iphone

How can i have a uitextview value be taken and send to a predefined url using obj-c only without any html /php.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can take the contents of a UITextView and then pass that content as HTTP POST or GET to a URL. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, are there any examples or source code of this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at NSURL. Use the text value of the UITextView as a parameter.

e.g.

```
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:MY_TEXTVIEW.text];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *methodString = @"method";
NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value=%@", textField.text];
NSString *apiRoot = @"http://www.domain.com";   
NSURL *apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@?%@", apiRoot,methodString,parameterString]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:apiUrl];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```